# Error during qt installation

Tags: qt, gcc

When I tried to run

> qt-linux-opensource-5.0.2-x86-offline.run

I got the following error:

> Error during installation process (qt.502.gcc.essentials):
>   Execution failed(Unexpected exit code: 127)

Some threads say this is because of absence of gcc on the machine, however my Ubuntu machine has gcc installed. Can someone tell me how to install qt?

Comment: Have you followed one of the numerous Wiki threads on installing Qt?  What verison of Ubuntu are you running and why that version of Qt when the current release is 5.7 ?

Comment: Do you perhaps have 64 bit Ubuntu? That is 32-bit Qt. You may be missing some 32 bit libraries or dev packages.

Comment: Also, why so old Qt, 5.0? But I would recommend the online installer anyway.

Comment: You should use the package manager of your Ubuntu distribution. If it's for development, install the `qtbase5-dev` package.